# Trouble making new lines while writing

Tags: php

I am making an image that logs the IP of everyone that visits it (for a security). Here is the code:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(1, 1);
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$farmerbase = "farmers/" . basename(__FILE__, '.php') . ".txt";
file_put_contents($farmerbase, $ip . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

How can I make it not log the same IP 3 times, and make sure it puts them on separate lines?

Comment: I assume you are referring to <br/>? I am writing to a text document, not a web page.

Comment: You have already put "\n" for new line. You might open text file in notepad i guess. Open txt file in browser or any editor.

Comment: Anything on how to make it not log 3 times for a single hit?

Comment: Open the file in wordpad or in notepad++

Comment: Tried to make a "debounce". Now it logs twice?
http://pastebin.com/6bvvnWdD

Comment: use 'PHP_EOL' instead of '\n' for text files

Comment: What's in the file after you've hit the page several times? (maybe with a few seconds in between)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't concatenate with a \n, take that out and see what happens

Comment: it just adds 4 more every time.

Comment: Please c&p the whole file (after 2-3 hits). Is the script called directly or as image in a larger html file?

Comment: It is called directly I am pretty sure,

Comment: After 3 hits http://pastebin.com/MjCi36ef

Comment: So 1. There are line-breaks after all - and 2. There is two lines per hit. -- So either PHP has an obvious bug or you are executing this script twice per page hit. --- What is the script called and what do you enter in the address-line in your browser?

Comment: a direct link to the php file. example.com/image.php

Comment: If you want to open the logfile in a standard Windows editor you should use `\r\n` instead of only `\n`. The carriage return (`\r`) is needed in windows.

Comment: To deduplicate you really need a database of some kind or another, or a whole lot more of expensive processing code. The way you're doing it right now it's somewhere between impractical and impossible to deduplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. The missing line breaks**

As mentioned in the comments to your question there is different ways to encode a [Newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) in different operating systems. To avoid such issues you would usually use the built-in constant `PHP_EOL` which is the proper newline for the platform running PHP. In your case the server is perhaps running on a different platform then you local machine. So if you want windows newlines you need to use `"\r\n"` for Mac it's `"\r"`.

**2. Two lines per webpage hit**

The script obviously writes only one line each time it is called. So I suspect it is running twice each time you hit whichever URL it is you are using. To prove that you could modify the script to add a random number to each line:

```
file_put_contents($farmerbase, $ip . ':' . rand() . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Now if the two lines are identical, then `file_put_contents()` accidentally writes the lines twice. If the lines differ you know the script is executed twice (either by entering the URL twice, by some issue with the server setup or because you are actually loading the page twice).